# is boost::lockfree::queue not lockfree with c++11?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, queue, lock-free

I'm trying to substitute `boost::lockfree::queue` for `std::queue` in this websocket++ example https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp

It looks like it can be done without really changing any syntax yet removing the `boost::unique_lock` lines.

However, when I look at the boost example, it has a code section that checks for lockfree http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html

When I look through the docs on `lockfree::queue`, it says this on `is_lock_free()` http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html:

> bool is_lock_free(void) const;
>
> **Warning**
>
> It only checks, if the queue head and tail nodes and the
>   freelist can be modified in a lock-free manner. On most platforms, the
>   whole implementation is lock-free, if this is true. Using c++0x-style
>   atomics, there is no possibility to provide a completely accurate
>   implementation, because one would need to test every internal node,
>   which is impossible if further nodes will be allocated from the
>   operating system.
>
> **Returns**: true, if implementation is lock-free.

I have no idea what "c++0x-style atomics" are, but I'm pretty sure that c++0x mean c++11.

I'm using c++11 and merely substituting `boost::lockfree::queue` for `std::queue`, so will this not be implemented lockfree?

Comment: I urge you to measure before committing to lock-free algorithms -- they're neat but designed to be _scalable_ and _safe_ (ie. prevent priority inversion) -- performance is of less concern and typically worse. For instance, Boost's lock-free queue implementation will be slower than a locked `std::queue` unless you've got several cores and a very high amount of contention.

Comment: `I have no idea what "c++0x-style atomics" are` is talking about [boost::atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/doc/html/atomic.html) which the library relies upon.

Comment: +1 for  the lib example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The "no possibility to provide a completely accurate implementation" comment refers to `is_lock_free()` - ie it is not guaranteed that `is_lock_free()` returns a result which accurately reflects whether the implementation is lock free. However, if `is_lock_free()` returns true, it's pretty likely that the implementation is lock free - but not absolutely, cast iron guaranteed.

Comment: Thank-you!  Would you say it's safe to use with the example above, or should I expect lost messages/connections on a regular basis?

Comment: Why would you expect something to get lost?

Comment: @CoryNelson Because I'm completely c++ inexperienced.  `is_lock_free` makes it sound like there might be situations where it's not lock free, so something "bad" might happen like lost messages/connections.

Comment: I think you probably want to read about what a [lock-free algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free) is.

Comment: if `is_lock_free` is false, that only means that it will use locks internally. The algorithm will still be thread-safe, just without the extra properties people use lock-free algorithms for.

Comment: @CoryNelson Please expand to answer for + n chk.

Comment: Honestly, that's a very different question (basically, "what is a lock-free algorithm") as opposed to your original question, which is about whether a specific algorithm in a specific library is lock-free.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Can you update your answer to include Cory's info?  While you definitely added important knowledge (and my upvote stands; I don't understand who just dvoted u), Cory better understood the original intent relative to my hyper ignorance.  lol

Comment: I don't honestly think that would be useful to other readers of the site - people aren't going to look at a specific question on `boost::lockfree::queue` for general information on what a lock-free algorithm is. If you think that kind of information would be useful to other readers of the site, can I suggest you ask a different question instead? (although think carefully about which SE site it should be on and whether it's been asked before).

Answer (score -7):

> I have no idea what "c++0x-style atomics" are, but I'm pretty sure that c++0x mean c++11.

- c++0x refers to c++03 and/or c++07 C++ standards.
- c++1x usually refers to c++11
- c++1y refers to c++11 successor.

Comment: That's totally incorrect. Both C++0x and C++1x refer to c++11. c++1y refers to either c++14 or c++17, but usually the former.